# select2 library I want when entering the search input to convert to uppercase letter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

If you can help me, I want that when writing in the select2 search box it automatically changes to uppercase
I have no code to teach because I have searched and found nothing about it
I attach an image

I put the inputs in automatic capital letters with onkeyup and I call the following function and I would like to do it in the select2

```
 function mayus(e) {
  e.value = e.value.toUpperCase();
 }
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGhc4.png)

Comment: Pasante, please make sure to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and come back to re-edit your question with more details, for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `onkeyup` property on the select2 search input. You should instead use *"event delegation"*. Try this

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function(e){
    e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
});
```

Comment: Ruleboy, I think he is searching for jquery, where while he is typing in the textarea the characters are automatically and mostly `instantly` turn to uppercase.

Comment: @PeriklisKakarakidis which textarea? You mean the search field?

Comment: yes search field

Comment: I do not want a function like this but it is not put in the select 2

Comment: function mayus(e) {
  e.value = e.value.toUpperCase();
}

Comment: @Pasante can you edit your question and add the javascript part as well?

Comment: ready already edited it